# Razor ASP.NET: update statuses for few instances with 1 POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I have a Model SkillStatus with fields ID, EmployeeID, SkillID and Status. I want user to have a possibility to view statuses of Employee`s skills in one page and change one or few statuses. To do this, I am using foreach loops in view and controller. Unfortunately, when I press "Save" status remains the same. Here are my controller, view and model:

```
namespace RazorSkillMatrix.Pages.Employees
{
    public class EditSkillModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RazorSkillMatrix.Data.RazorSkillMatrixContext _context;

        public EditSkillModel(RazorSkillMatrix.Data.RazorSkillMatrixContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public Employee? Employee { get; set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty]
        public ICollection<SkillStatus> SkillStatuses { get; set; } = default!;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(SkillStatusViewModel skill_status)
        {
            if (skill_status != null && skill_status.SkillStatuses != null && Employee != null)

        {
            foreach (var item in skill_status.SkillStatuses)
            {
                var existingSkillStatus = await _context.SkillStatus.Where(e => e.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                if (existingSkillStatus != null)
                {
                    existingSkillStatus.Status = item.Status;
                }
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}

@page
@model RazorSkillMatrix.Pages.Employees.EditSkillModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditSkill";
}

<h1 class="text-center mb-4">Edit Skills for @Model.Employee?.FullName</h1>

@if (Model.SkillStatuses != null)
{
    <form method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Skill</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var skillstatus in Model.SkillStatuses)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@skillstatus.Skill.Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@skillstatus.Id" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@skillstatus.EmployeeId" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@skillstatus.SkillId" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select asp-for="@skillstatus.Status" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="false">No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
}

<div class="mt-4">
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}

public class SkillStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [DisplayName("Employee")]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Skill")]
        public int SkillId { get; set; }
        public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
public class SkillStatusViewModel
{
    public List<SkillStatus>? SkillStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

According to Debugger, I get the list of current SkillStatuses but the Status itself is not being updated. I tried to bind Status between view and controller, using name, but it did not help. I also tried different options of [Bind Property] but the result was the same. I have just started learning C# and Razor, so might just missed something simple...

Comment: Do you get the value of the `id` ? I test your code, and I cannot get the `id`.

Comment: I think it was a mistake to pass "ID" as a POST method parameter, because user might change few SkillStatuses at once. Therefore I added SkillStatusViewModel and modified my POST method (now it takes "SkillStatusViewModel skill_status" parameter). Unfortunately, it still does not work...

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at  POST method (SkillStatusViewModel skill_status) to see if you can get the value .

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to bind Status between view and controller, using name, but
> it did not help

You can try to use `asp-for="@Model.SkillStatuses[@i].Status"` to bind each Status.

I have a work demo like below, you can refer to it.

EditSkillModel:

```
        public Employee? Employee { get; set; } = default!;
        public Skill Skill { get; set; }
        
        [BindProperty]
        public List<SkillStatus> SkillStatuses { get; set; } = default!;
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(List<SkillStatus> SkillStatuses)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
               
            if (SkillStatuses != null )

                {
                    foreach (var item in SkillStatuses)
                    {
                        var existingSkillStatus = await _context.SkillStatus.Where(e => e.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                        if (existingSkillStatus != null)
                        {
                            existingSkillStatus.Status = item.Status;
                        }
                    }
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

           
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

EditSkillModel.cshtml:

```
@if (Model.SkillStatuses != null)
{
    <form method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Skill</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>            
         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SkillStatuses.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Skill.Name</td>
                        <td>
                         
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillStatuses[@i].Id" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillStatuses[@i].EmployeeId" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillStatuses[@i].SkillId" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select asp-for="@Model.SkillStatuses[@i].Status" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="false">No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

result:

[image]

**Note**: I add `?`  to avoid ModelState.IsValid is false:

```
public virtual Employee? Employee { get; set; }
 public virtual Skill? Skill { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was related to `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` line - I placed it after foreach cycle and changes were not saved. To make everything work, just place it inside if statement after line `existingSkillStatus.Status = item.Status;`